# intellij+griffon.0.9.5 No such property: withSql?

Tags: griffon

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: withSql for class: org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1_closure2_closure7_closure8.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy:14)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1_closure2_closure7.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy:13)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1_closure2_closure7.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy:12)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy:11)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView$_run_closure1.doCall(AddressbookView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:167)
    at addressbook.AddressbookView.run(AddressbookView.groovy:10)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:151)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:155)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)

Answer (score 0):

The GSQL/Datasource plugins do not inject the `withSql`method to Views by default, you must change the configuration (explained in the plugin's page). However I'd strongly recommend not to inject such method in a View as views are built inside the UI thread, making database calls inside this thread is really a bad idea.